# Dropbox integrated Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm attempting to upload files from a chrome extension to dropbox using the saver api. When the saver window loads however, no files are displayed in the GUI.
Clicking save or cancel does nothing. More importantly (I think), in the background the console throws the following message:

> Unable to post message to
>   chrome-extension://[chrome extension ID]. Recipient has
>   origin https://www.dropbox.com.

I've read the [cross-origin extension documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html), and I believe I have my manifest file configured correctly. It is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "Pic Grabber",
  "version": "2.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs", "<all_urls>", "background", 
    "http://*/*", 
    "https://*/*", 
    "http://*", 
    "https://*"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [{
        "js": ["grabber.js"],
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
    }],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Download pictures from this page.",
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/1/dropins.js; object-src 'self'"
}
```

I've verified the dropin works on some test code on a server I have access to. Relevent results of diff of the server (which works) and extension GET requests are as follows:

```
Server:
Request URL:https://www.dropbox.com/saver?origin=[SERVER'S ORIGIN]&app_key=[APP KEY]
Extension:
Request URL:https://www.dropbox.com/saver?origin=chrome-extension[CHROME EXTENSION ID]&app_key=[SAME APP KEY]

Server:
referer:[PATH TO TEST HTML FILE ON SERVER]
(No referer on Extension)

Server:
url:/saver?origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.uvm.edu&app_key=7tvbf4mpgd2v56z
Extension:
url:/saver?origin=chrome-extension[CHROME EXTENSION ID]&app_key=[APP KEY]

Server:
origin:[SERVER DOMAIN]
Extension:
origin:chrome-extension://[CHROME EXTENSION ID]
```

The html of my extension popup is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- used to display the images found by the scripts and offer a save to dropbox button -->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>PicGrabber</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h3>Download the following pictures:</h1>
    <hr>
    <div id="btn-container"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/1/dropins.js" id="dropboxjs" data-app-key="[KEY]"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

(popup.js is the source of my content-script that performs the bulk of the work of the extension. This script appears to be working correctly, but if I would help I'd be happy to post it as well).

I'm afraid I'm not sure exactly where the error lies. It seems that somehow, the dropbox API is unable to communicate properly with the extension, resulting in a malformed popup that cannot communicate with the Dropbox server.

Any tips/pointers in the right direction would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: I've added the popup.js code to this post in the hope it will help-

```
/**
    This is the popup.js file, used to receive the list of urls that the grabber content script has found and expose them to the popup.html file.
**/

function get_urls() {
  var picUrls = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().IMAGE_URLS;
  if (picUrls){
    console.log("The popup.js is working")

    // create a container object for the list
    var listContainer = document.createElement("div");  
    // add it to the DOm
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(listContainer);
    // create a ul object for the list items
    var listElement = document.createElement("ul");
    // add that to the DOm
    listContainer.appendChild(listElement);

    saveThese = []

    // loop through the urls, and append them to the ul object
    for (var i = picUrls.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      var listItem = document.createElement("li");
      // listItem.innerHTML = "<a href='" + picUrls[i].src +"'>" + picUrls[i].name + "</a><img src='" + picUrls[i].src + "'width=25%, height=25%></img>";
      listItem.innerHTML = "<img src='" + picUrls[i].src + "'width=25%, height=25%></img>";
      listElement.appendChild(listItem);

      saveThese.push({
        'url':picUrls[i].src,
        'filename':picUrls[i].name
      });
    }

    // create dropbox saver dropin
    options = {
      files: saveThese,
      success: function() {},
      progress: function(progress) {},
      cancel: function() {},
      error: function(errmsg) {}
    } // end options
  }

  Dropbox.createSaveButton(options);
  var btn = Dropbox.createSaveButton(options);
  document.getElementById('btn-container').appendChild(btn); 
}

window.onload = get_urls();
```

Comment: I am not familiar with the saver API, but the answer yo this question might be relevant.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Which answer are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to **[this  answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19674172/chrome-extension-and-dropbox-dropin-saver-error/19687063#19687063)**.

Comment: That was actually an answer to a separate issue I was having which has been resolved.

Comment: Could there be something in the grabber.js script causing the problem?

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19687101/1808164) other question? Did you add the chrome extension ID in the Drop-ins domains in the Dropbox App Console?